# Putting Header HTML into one file

Tags: html

I have a header on my website that I would like to put into one file, like CSS files, so I only have to edit one file to add or remove content rather than 8.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need some server-side technology to build HTML files with common files included.  PHP, Ruby on Rails, Node.js with Express, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the traditional server-side solutions mentioned by Brad, you can also try shtml (server side includes). See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). It's supported by Apache, nginx, lighttpd, and more.

Comment: I followed the guide on the apache docs, but it's not working.

Comment: Well I can't help you if you don't tell me what part is not working or what you've tried.